# Run computer vision model on every frame of live camera preview with platform channels/CoreML?

Tags: flutter, mobile, computer-vision, object-detection, coreml

I would like to run an object detection model (image goes in, detected bounding boxes go out) on every frame of the live camera preview at approx. 15 fps. I trained a model and converted it to CoreML as I want to target iOS first.

Is it feasible to use platform channels and send every frame from the camera stream to a swift method that runs the CoreML model? Does this add too much overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is feasible (although I have no idea what you mean by platform channels) and depending on the model you can get much more than 15 fps.